# How to sum totals from a subquery using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an existing query that spits out total hours for each employee for each day.  I need to get total hours between the two given dates for each employee.  So basically I need to sum up the hours column for each employee.
Here is my existing query that gives totals per day:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pe.first, ' ', pe.last) AS Name,
           tp.EmpID AS 'Empl ID',
           DATE_FORMAT(tp.PunchDateTime, '%m-%d-%Y') AS 'Punch Date',
           TRUNCATE(
              (  SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(PunchDateTime) * (1 - 2 * `In-Out`))
               / 3600),
              2)
              AS 'Hours Worked'
      FROM    timeclock_punchlog tp
           LEFT JOIN
              prempl01 pe
           ON tp.EmpID = pe.prempl
     WHERE     tp.PunchDateTime >= '2013-5-26'
           AND tp.PunchDateTime < '2013-6-1'
    GROUP BY date(PunchDateTime), EmpID
    ORDER BY EmpID ASC
```

And it gives output like this:

```
Name                Empl ID Punch Date  Hours Worked
TERESA A. EUBANKS   0354    05-29-2013      0.00
TRACY D CURTIS      0364    05-28-2013      6.15
TRACY D CURTIS      0364    05-29-2013      0.00
KENT KADAVY         0452    05-31-2013      2.38
JANE M SMITH        0456    05-31-2013      0.02
JANE M SMITH        0456    05-29-2013      0.01
JANE M SMITH        0456    05-28-2013      3.15
CINDY JEAN ARREY    0458    05-28-2013      8.16
```

Basically I want a query that will take that output above and show the sum of the hours worked for each employee.  I don't need to show the hours worked per day.

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: This should help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: add in some sum() and add a `weekofyear(punchdatetime)` to the group-by?

Comment: well, the dates are arbitrary.  They could span multiple weeks or a few days.

Comment: @CBroe I assume you are hinting at the 'WITH ROLLUP' modifier.  I have tried working with that and could never get it to do what I wanted.

Comment: You should group by EmpId first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making it way to complicated.  No subquery needed.  Here is my final query to produce my desired results.

```
    SELECT CONCAT(pe.first, ' ', pe.last) AS Name,
       tp.EmpID AS 'Empl ID',
       DATE_FORMAT(tp.PunchDateTime, '%m-%d-%Y') AS 'Punch Date',
       TRUNCATE(
          (SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(PunchDateTime) * (1 - 2 * `In-Out`)) / 3600),
          3)
          AS 'Hours Worked'
  FROM timeclock_punchlog tp LEFT JOIN prempl01 pe ON tp.EmpID = pe.prempl
 WHERE tp.PunchDateTime >= '2013-5-1' AND tp.PunchDateTime < '2013-5-28'
GROUP BY tp.EmpID;
```